# Please explain Space Engineers Advanced Server Search

Tags: space-engineers

I try to use the Advanced Server Search in Space Engineers. But somehow I never get the results I want. Maybe I just don't get the meaning of the icons. There are three different status of these checkboxes:

- Filled with square
- Filled with dash
- Empty

I guess the first one (filled with square) says "I want that feature". But I'm not sure about the others. Please enlighten me.

[image: Advanced Server Search Screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my research, it seems the following is true

- Dash sign: the feature can be on or off
  [image: Space Engineers Advanced Search Minus Sign]
- Empty box: the feature is off for the server
  [image: Space Engineers Advanced Search Empty Box]
- Filled box: the feature is on for the server
  [image: Space Engineers Advanced Search Filled Box]

This is something not well documented and had to test for my research. My testing process was:

1. Access Advanced tab of the Advanced Server Search
2. Set one box to blank, filled, or dash then click Search
3. Select a server then click Server Details
   [image: Space Engineers Advanced Search Server Details]
4. Look for the world setting changed on step 2 and document if it's on or off
   [image: Space Engineers Advanced Search World Settings]
5. Repeat steps 1-4 until all box options have been tested